# In ArrayBlockingQueue, why copy final member field into local final variable?

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, final, local-variables

In `ArrayBlockingQueue`, all the methods that require the lock copy it to a local `final` variable before calling `lock()`.

```
public boolean offer(E e) {
    if (e == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        if (count == items.length)
            return false;
        else {
            insert(e);
            return true;
        }
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Is there any reason to copy `this.lock` to a local variable `lock` when the field `this.lock` is `final`?

Additionally, it also uses a local copy of `E[]` before acting on it:

```
private E extract() {
    final E[] items = this.items;
    E x = items[takeIndex];
    items[takeIndex] = null;
    takeIndex = inc(takeIndex);
    --count;
    notFull.signal();
    return x;
}
```

Is there any reason for copying a final field to a local final variable?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It's an extreme optimization Doug Lea, the author of the class, likes to use. Here's a post on [a recent thread](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-May/004165.html) on the core-libs-dev mailing list about this exact subject which answers your question pretty well.

from the post:

> ...copying to locals produces the smallest
>   bytecode, and for low-level code it's nice to write code
>   that's a little closer to the machine

Comment: Strong emphasis on "extreme"!  This is not a general-purpose good programming practice that everyone should be emulating.

Comment: Random FYI: in some other cases when you see this done, it's because the field in question is volatile, and the method needs to make sure it's got a single consistent value or reference for it throughout.

Comment: I'll take this "extreme" optimization in a core class like this.

Comment: Ok, the copying trick is clear. But why copy to a final local variable? Just to give a hint to one who reads the code, or it gives some hidden bytecode profit as well?

Comment: @zamza Isn't that what I answered here? It produces smaller bytecode.

Comment: I understand that copying to local produces smaller code, but this local variable could have been not final. I wonder if local variable finality makes any difference. I.e. is `final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;` somehow different from `ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;`

Comment: @zamza, local final variables are only used by java compiler, not the bytecode (i.e. JVM doesn't know if a local variable is final)

Comment: In addition to bytecode size, is this an optimization also for execution speed ?

Comment: @SantiBailors: AFAIK there's no execution speed benefit, but I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 13):

[This thread](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2011-January/007703.html) gives some answers. In substance:

- the compiler can't easily prove that a final field does not change within a method (due to reflection / serialization etc.)
- most current compilers actually don't try and would therefore have to reload the final field everytime it is used which could lead to a cache miss or a page fault
- storing it in a local variable forces the JVM to perform only one load

Comment: I don't think a `final` variable has to be reloaded by the JVM. If you modify a `final` variable via reflection, you lose guarantee of your program working correctly (meaning the new value might not be taken into account in all cases).