# Why do we make a copy of final instance variable in a method in Java?

Tags: java, final

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In ArrayBlockingQueue, why copy final member field into local final variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785964/in-arrayblockingqueue-why-copy-final-member-field-into-local-final-variable)

For instance:

```
private final Object o;

public void doSomething(){

    final Object local = this.o;
    //access methods of local;

}
```

This practice is followed in lots of java classes (such as ArrayBlockingQueue). What's the benefit of this?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785964/in-arrayblockingqueue-why-copy-final-member-field-into-local-final-variable/2786019

Comment: A more concrete example would be useful.  In `ArrayBlockingQueue` a `ReentrantLock` is used for instance