# Is there a reason to copy a final variable to a local variable?

Tags: java, final

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In ArrayBlockingQueue, why copy final member field into local final variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785964/in-arrayblockingqueue-why-copy-final-member-field-into-local-final-variable)

Check out this code from ThreadPoolExecutor:

```
private final ReentrantLock mainLock = new ReentrantLock();

...

private void ensureQueuedTaskHandled(Runnable command) {
        final ReentrantLock mainLock = this.mainLock;
        mainLock.lock();
```

Why is `this.mainLock` copied to a local variable?
I know this pattern is useful to ensure the field doesn't change, but we're talking about a final field here. Is it still relevant?