# ReentrantLock synchronizing getters and setters

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, reentrantlock

Let's say you have the following code:

```
public int getSpeedX() {
    speedLock.lock();
    try {
        return speedX;
    } finally {
        speedLock.unlock();
    }
}

public void setSpeedX(int x) {
    speedLock.lock();
    try {
        speedX = x;
    } finally {
        speedLock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Is the return speedX OK? or should it be:

```
public int getSpeedX() {
    int temp;
    speedLock.lock();
    try {
        temp = speedX;
    } finally {
        speedLock.unlock();
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Which is correct? Or are they equivalent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are equivalent.  Anything in a `finally` block is executed, no matter how the block is exited (e.g. flow control out the bottom, return statement, or exception).

Comment: Not quite true; from what I understand, if you put a `System.exit(int exitcode)` in a try, the finally won't be executed...

Comment: I would imagine that System.exit is a special case since it wants to immediately halt the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

They both work and are same. The first one is optimized though. 
Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019831/java-lock-variable-assignment-before-use-why) and that should answer your question. and this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785964/in-arrayblockingqueue-why-copy-final-member-field-into-local-final-variable) in the first link that says

> copying to locals produces the smallest bytecode, and for low-level code it's nice to write code that's a little closer to the machine

Answer (score 0):

java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantReadWriteLock

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html

Answer (score 0):

I will go for the first one which keeps the getter signature clean and tidy (no parameters). 
I would put a small comment there to document the fact that the `finally` block is always executed. 
For the record, I actually got the exact same question from a colleague of mine once, from that point and on, I always try to comment this kind of coding to save some googling time for my code readers.