# what's the benefit of the code

Tags: concurrency, locking, java

While reading the source code of ArrayBlockingQueue, I found below code:

```
public E take() throws InterruptedException {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        try {
            while (count == 0)
                notEmpty.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            notEmpty.signal(); // propagate to non-interrupted thread
            throw ie;
        }
        E x = extract();
        return x;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

why not use the code

```
public E take() throws InterruptedException {
     lock.lockInterruptibly();
    try {
        try {
            while (count == 0)
                notEmpty.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ie) {
            notEmpty.signal(); // propagate to non-interrupted thread
            throw ie;
        }
        E x = extract();
        return x;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

what's the Benefit of  the line code :**final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;**

Comment: @assylias .possible duplicate

Answer (score 0):

This idea was popularized by Doug Lea - I think that the original idea was that the JVM could possibly perform some performance related optimization when there was a final local variable used.

Check out [this](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/core-libs-dev/2010-May/004165.html) thread from the OpenJDK thread which discusses this very question

Edit:

A little research threw up these two related questions on stack:

[In ArrayBlockingQueue, why copy final member field into local final variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785964/in-arrayblockingqueue-why-copy-final-member-field-into-local-final-variable)

[Java Lock variable assignment before use. Why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8019831/java-lock-variable-assignment-before-use-why)

Comment: This is not the best reference - [this other thread](http://cs.oswego.edu/pipermail/concurrency-interest/2011-January/007703.html) is more informative.