# Why is lock captured to a local variable

Tags: java, reentrantlock

In java JRE I saw [the code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/harmony/standard/classlib/trunk/modules/concurrent/src/main/java/java/util/concurrent/DelayQueue.java)

```
private final ReentrantLock lock;
public E poll() {
        final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lock();
```

Why is lock captured to a private variable? I would expect simply

```
public E poll() {
        lock.lock();
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785964/in-arrayblockingqueue-why-copy-final-member-field-into-local-final-variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primarily it is to ensure maximum performance. Although this is a real micro-optimisation, it's probably in performance-sensitive code, and you might as well make it.

You also need to be *very* careful that the lock reference you are using doesn't mutate. Sure make the field `final`, but taking a `final` local reference is locally explicit.

Comment: What does it optimize? is accessing a final class member slower than a local final member?

Comment: @EugeneRetunsky if you look at the duplicate post and what it quotes: "copying to locals produces the smallest bytecode"

Comment: Yes, but this is really microscopic. And from the performance point you won't notice that - even at nanoseconds level, I believe. Especially comparing to locking/unlocking. Also, it saves only ONE access to the field and makes code less clear with non-noticeable result in performance.

Comment: Well, it's not that simple -- it could save you a whole cache miss, or even a page fault. The reasons to do it outweigh the reasons not to do it.

Comment: I believe the performance was measured. Doug's like that. Also bytecode size affects whether HotSpot inlines.