# Why jdk code style uses a variable assignment and read on the same line - eg. (i=2) < max

Tags: java, java-collections-api

I noticed that in the jdk source code and more specifically in the collections framework there is a preference in assigning variables right before reading them in expressions. Is it just a simple preference or is it something more important which I am not aware of? One reason that I can think of is that the variable is used in this expression only.

As I am not used to this style I find it hard to read it. The code is very condensed. Below you can see an example taken from `java.util.HashMap.getNode()`

```
Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> first, e; int n; K k;
if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 && ...) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Doug Lea, who writes most of that code, is known for going to ridiculous lengths for optimization and code size and the like.  That code could be done more simply, but equivalently, more spread out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As already mentioned in the comment: Doug Lea, who is one of the main authors of the collections framework and the concurrency packages, tends to do optimizations that may look confusing (or even counterintuitive) for mere mortals.

<sub>A "famous" example here is [copying fields to local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785964/in-arrayblockingqueue-why-copy-final-member-field-into-local-final-variable) in order to minimize the size of the bytecode, which is actually also done with the `table` field and the local `tab` variable in the example that you referred to!</sub>

---

For very simple tests, it does not seem to make a difference (referring to the resulting bytecode size) whether the accesses are "inlined" or not. So I tried to create an example that roughly resembles the structures of the `getNode` method that you mentioned: An access to a field that is an array, a length check, an access to a field of one array element...

- The `testSeparate` method does separate assignments and checks
- The `testInlined` method uses the assignment-in-if-style
- The `testRepeated` method (as a counterexample) does every access repeatedly

The code:

```
class Node
{
    int k;
    int j;
}

public class AssignAndUseTestComplex
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        AssignAndUseTestComplex t = new AssignAndUseTestComplex();
        t.testSeparate(1);
        t.testInlined(1);
        t.testRepeated(1);
    }

    private Node table[] = new Node[] { new Node() };

    int testSeparate(int value)
    {
        Node[] tab = table;
        if (tab != null)
        {
            int n = tab.length;
            if (n > 0)
            {
                Node first = tab[(n-1)];
                if (first != null)
                {
                    return first.k+first.j;
                }
            }
        } 
        return 0;
    }

    int testInlined(int value)
    {
        Node[] tab; Node first, e; int n;
        if ((tab = table) != null && (n = tab.length) > 0 && 
            (first = tab[(n - 1)]) != null) {
            return first.k+first.j;
        }
        return 0;
    }

    int testRepeated(int value)
    {
        if (table != null)
        {
            if (table.length > 0)
            {
                if (table[(table.length-1)] != null)
                {
                    return table[(table.length-1)].k+table[(table.length-1)].j;
                }
            }
        } 
        return 0;
    }

}
```

And the resulting bytecodes: The `testSeparate` method uses **41 instructions**:

```
  int testSeparate(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #15                 // Field table:[Lstackoverflow/Node;
       4: astore_2
       5: aload_2
       6: ifnull        40
       9: aload_2
      10: arraylength
      11: istore_3
      12: iload_3
      13: ifle          40
      16: aload_2
      17: iload_3
      18: iconst_1
      19: isub
      20: aaload
      21: astore        4
      23: aload         4
      25: ifnull        40
      28: aload         4
      30: getfield      #37                 // Field stackoverflow/Node.k:I
      33: aload         4
      35: getfield      #41                 // Field stackoverflow/Node.j:I
      38: iadd
      39: ireturn
      40: iconst_0
      41: ireturn
```

The `testInlined` method indeed is a tad smaller, with **39 instructions**

```
  int testInlined(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #15                 // Field table:[Lstackoverflow/Node;
       4: dup
       5: astore_2
       6: ifnull        38
       9: aload_2
      10: arraylength
      11: dup
      12: istore        5
      14: ifle          38
      17: aload_2
      18: iload         5
      20: iconst_1
      21: isub
      22: aaload
      23: dup
      24: astore_3
      25: ifnull        38
      28: aload_3
      29: getfield      #37                 // Field stackoverflow/Node.k:I
      32: aload_3
      33: getfield      #41                 // Field stackoverflow/Node.j:I
      36: iadd
      37: ireturn
      38: iconst_0
      39: ireturn
```

Finally, the `testRepeated` method uses a whopping **63 instructions**

```
  int testRepeated(int);
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: getfield      #15                 // Field table:[Lstackoverflow/Node;
       4: ifnull        62
       7: aload_0
       8: getfield      #15                 // Field table:[Lstackoverflow/Node;
      11: arraylength
      12: ifle          62
      15: aload_0
      16: getfield      #15                 // Field table:[Lstackoverflow/Node;
      19: aload_0
      20: getfield      #15                 // Field table:[Lstackoverflow/Node;
      23: arraylength
      24: iconst_1
      25: isub
      26: aaload
      27: ifnull        62
      30: aload_0
      31: getfield      #15                 // Field table:[Lstackoverflow/Node;
      34: aload_0
      35: getfield      #15                 // Field table:[Lstackoverflow/Node;
      38: arraylength
      39: iconst_1
      40: isub
      41: aaload
      42: getfield      #37                 // Field stackoverflow/Node.k:I
      45: aload_0
      46: getfield      #15                 // Field table:[Lstackoverflow/Node;
      49: aload_0
      50: getfield      #15                 // Field table:[Lstackoverflow/Node;
      53: arraylength
      54: iconst_1
      55: isub
      56: aaload
      57: getfield      #41                 // Field stackoverflow/Node.j:I
      60: iadd
      61: ireturn
      62: iconst_0
      63: ireturn
```

So it seems that this "obscure" way of writing the queries and assignments can, indeed, save a few bytes of bytecode, and (given the justification in the linked answer about storing fields in local variables) this may have been the reason to use this style.

### But...

in any case: After the method has been executed a few times, the JIT will kick in, and the resulting machine code will have "nothing" to do with the original bytecode - and I'm pretty sure that all three versions will actually be compiled to the same machine code in the end.

So the bottom line is: Don't use this style. Instead, just [write dumb code](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/devinsight-1-139780.html) that is easy to read and maintain. You'll know when it's your turn to use "optimizations" like these.

---

> EDIT: A short addendum...

I have made a further test, and compared the `testSeparate` and `testInlined` method concerning the actual *machine code* that is generated by the JIT.

I modified the `main` method a bit, to prevent unrealistic over-optimizations or other shortcuts that the JIT might take, but the actual methods have been left unmodified.

And as expected: When calling the methods a few thousand times with a hotspot disassembly JVM and `-XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions -XX:+LogCompilation -XX:+PrintAssembly`, then the actual machine code of both methods is *identical*.

So once more, the JIT does its job pretty well, and the programmer can focus on writing *readable* code (whatever that means).

> ... and and a minor correction/clarification:

I did not test the third method, `testRepeated`, because it is *not equivalent* to the other methods (and thus, it *can* not result in the same machine code). This is, by the way, another small advantage of the strategy of storing fields in local variables: It offers a (*very* limited, but sometimes handy) form of "*thread safety*": It is made sure that the length of an array (like the `tab` array in the `getNode` method of `HashMap`) can not change while the method is being executed.