# assign instance field to local variable

Tags: java

This is `keySet()` method on `HashMap` class from JDK. Why did the author assign the field `keySet` to local variable `ks`?

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks;
    return (ks = keySet) == null ? (keySet = new KeySet()) : ks;
}
```

What is the difference between the above and the below? Does this have something to do with thread-safety?

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    return (keySet == null ? (keySet = new KeySet()) : keySet;
}
```

Comment: Maybe; though it also looks like he's trying to set a class level variable while ensuring that variable is not null and returning that value. I've not a clue beyond that though. I'd need to look at the whole class.

Comment: Perhaps for clarity of intention

Comment: Could be considered as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/28975415/3182664 http://stackoverflow.com/q/2785964/3182664 http://stackoverflow.com/q/37776179/3182664 http://stackoverflow.com/q/32619269/3182664 and likely some others....

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand slightly on Michael's answer, I expect it is there to ensure that the `keySet()` method never returns `null`, possibly in addition to providing performance benefits noted.

Given this code:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    return (keySet == null ? (keySet = new KeySet()) : keySet;
}
```

It would be at least theoretically possible in multi-threaded code that the `keySet` field could be set to `null` between the first read (`keySet == null`) and the second read, where it is returned.  I haven't looked at the rest of the code, but I assume there are other places where `keySet` is potentially assigned `null`.  Whether this is as a result of an issue seen in the wild, or a defensive measure would be a question for the authors.

The actual code:

```
public Set<K> keySet() {
    Set<K> ks;
    return (ks = keySet) == null ? (keySet = new KeySet()) : ks;
}
```

...doesn't have this problem as the field is only read once.

Comment: Yup. This is about being safe in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: @msandiford it's not necessarily set to null somewhere, the operations could simply be re-ordered as there are two racy reads of the shared variable.

Answer (score 9):

If you look at the `keySet` declaration in the `abstract class AbstractMap<K,V>`, you will see that it is defined as:

```
transient volatile Set<K>  keySet;
```

Since it is volatile, reading it just once by using the local variable assignment is cheaper than reading it twice as would be in the other example you provided.

<s>Furthermore, if you were to return the `keySet` variable directly, then all the client code would be dealing with a volatile reference vs. a non-volatile reference (i.e. the `Set<K> ks`)</s>

Comment: Thanks for the answer about volatile field read, I haven't thought about it. Could you please explain "dealing with a volatile reference vs. a non-volatile reference" part ?

Comment: There's no such notion as a "volatile reference vs. a non-volatile reference".