# Understanding Java source code: Why is this null-handling logic so complicated?

Tags: java, null

I am reading the JDK source code. I see a method `public Collection<V> values()` in class `HashMap`:

```
   public Collection<V> values() {
        Collection<V> vs = values;
        if (vs == null) {
            vs = new Values();
            values = vs;
        }
        return vs;
    }
```

But I think this logic will be shorter and more concise:

```
public Collection<V> values() {
    if (values == null) {
        values = new Values();
    }
    return values;
}
```

I think there must be a reason behind this. Please tell me why.

Comment: I think in earlier java versions the first snippet *would* be faster, as you'd need to load the variable only once into a local reference. Though in later versions that effect is negligible and you should just access the instance member directly

Comment: Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957376/assign-instance-field-to-local-variable

Comment: @Lino for concurrent code things _are very different_ when assigning to a local variable first; for non-concurrent it leads to smaller byte-code if that ever matters