# Can someone help deconstruct this terse Java function into plain English?

Tags: java, xojo

I'm trying to port the `PriorityQueue` class from the [OpenJDK implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/PriorityQueue.java) to another language (Xojo) that doesn't have a similar data structure. I'm really struggling to break down the following method into pseudocode so I can translate it to Xojo:

```java
public E poll() {
  final Object[] es;
  final E result;

  if ((result = (E) ((es = queue)[0])) != null) {
    modCount++;
    final int n;
    final E x = (E) es[(n = --size)];
    es[n] = null;
    if (n > 0) {
      final Comparator<? super E> cmp;
      if ((cmp = comparator) == null)
        siftDownComparable(0, x, es, n);
      else
        siftDownUsingComparator(0, x, es, n, cmp);
      }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The variable `queue` is an `Object[]` array defined on the class.

There are a couple of lines that are confusing me. Firstly:

`if ((result = (E) ((es = queue)[0])) != null)`

Does this mean "assign the array `queue` to the variable `es` and access element `0` and do the following if it's **not** null?" What does the `result = (E)` expression mean? I know `E` is a generic type.

What is the order of operation of `final E x = (E) es[(n = --size)];`? Does this mean decrement `size`, assign that value to `n` and then access this index within the `es` array? If so, what does `x = (E)` before this expression mean? I'm guessing it means to cast the element to type `E`?

Lastly, these lines:

```java
final Comparator<? super E> cmp;
if ((cmp = comparator) == null)
```

`comparator` is a class variable (holding a `Comparator`). Why assign it to a local variable `cmp` and what does the question mark mean on the first line?

Comment: Just FYI, the code you are porting is licensed under GPLv2. This has implications for software that is derived from it, including ports. See https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/151515/rewrote-gnu-gpl-v2-code-in-another-language-can-i-change-a-license

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does this mean "assign the array queue to the variable `es`"

Yes.

> and access element 0 and do the following if it's not null?

Yes.

> What does the `result = (E)` expression mean?

At the same time as the two expressions above, it also assigns `queue[0]` to `result`.  The `(E)` is a cast to a type.  So it's basically just:

```
result = queue[0]
```

With some extra stuff thrown in.

> `final E x = (E) es[(n = --size)];`? Does this mean decrement `size`, assign that value to `n` and then access this index within the `es` array?

Yes.

> If so, what does `x = (E)` before this expression mean? I'm guessing it means to cast the element to type `E`?

Yes, again just a cast like before.

> `comparator` is a class variable

Just to be pedantic, `comparator` is likely an instance variable, not a class variable.  Check its definition.

> Why assign it to a local variable `cmp`

I suppose to make a local variable copy.  I don't see a good reason to do that in the code, so it might be a mistake or something that was left in after some previous code got changed.

> and what does the question mark mean on the first line?

The question mark means the type of the `Comparator` is unknown, and can be anything as long as it's a super class of `E`.  For example, if `Integer` doesn't have a `Comparator` but `Number` does, then that's OK, `Number` is a super class of `Integer` and that's good enough.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering the the individual points and providing a clear explanation. I'm very grateful.

Answer (score 2):

1-  `if ((result = (E) ((es = queue)[0])) != null)`
First it assigns the array `queue` to the variable `es`and gets element `0` from it the casts it t `E` generic type and assigns it to `result` then checks if `result` is not null.

2- `final E x = (E) es[(n = --size)];`
First java evaluates `--size` then assigns to int type `n` then gets `n`th from `es` array, casts it to `E`, and then assigns it to variable `x`.

I think the next two lines you asked are clear now!

Answer (score 2):

Let's see if I can help:

`if ((result = (E) ((es = queue)[0])) != null)`

The above means "assign `queue` to `es`, access index 0 of it, cast it to type `E`, assign it to `result` and do the following if it's not null".

`final E x = (E) es[(n = --size)];`

This means "substract one from `size` and assign the new value to `n`, use it as an index of `es` and cast that element to type `E`, then assign it to the final variable `x` of type `E`.

`final Comparator<? super E> cmp;`

The question mark is a wildcard. `<? super E>` means "some type which is an ancestor of E". As for why `comparator` is assigned to the local variable `cmp`, I'm not quite sure but I remember something similar being asked recently in another question. I'll see if I can find it and edit this answer. I hope that helps you at least a bit. If any of what I said is not clear just ask and I'll try to reword the explanation.

Edit: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37957376/assign-instance-field-to-local-variable) is the question I mentioned in the previous paragraph. The answers suggest performance benefits, but again I'm not sure if that's the reason in this case, as the specifics differ slightly.

Comment: Another +1 for the link to the reason for the local assignment. That one really was confounding me.