# ArrayBlockingQueue ReentrantLock coding style

Tags: java, java.util.concurrent

In java `ArrayBlockingQueue` implementation, locking is always performed following way.

Main lock is declared as final variable in the source code which makes sense.

```
   /** Main lock guarding all access */
    final ReentrantLock lock;
```

and in method, in order to lock, it does following way.

```
final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
        lock.lock();
```

What is the reasoning behind this and does general api user expects to do same style or is this for JDK specific special implementation?

Comment: You can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785964/in-arrayblockingqueue-why-copy-final-member-field-into-local-final-variable

Comment: ah thanks you very much. I should have searched harder...