# What is the benefit of creating local variables in methods that are just copies of instance variables?

Tags: java, concurrency, project-reactor

In some library implementations people use to create a lot of local variables that directly relate to instance variables. I don't really get the point. Maybe someone could shine some light in my darkness.

An example is the method `tryEmitNext(T t)` of the `EmitterProcessor` in Project Reactor core library. The code is:

```
@Override
public EmitResult tryEmitNext(T t) {
    if (done) {
        return Sinks.EmitResult.FAIL_TERMINATED;
    }

    Objects.requireNonNull(t, "onNext");

    Queue<T> q = queue;

    if (q == null) {
        if (Operators.setOnce(S, this, Operators.emptySubscription())) {
            q = Queues.<T>get(prefetch).get();
            queue = q;
        }
        else {
            for (; ; ) {
                if (isCancelled()) {
                    return EmitResult.FAIL_CANCELLED;
                }
                q = queue;
                if (q != null) {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if (!q.offer(t)) {
        return subscribers == EMPTY ? EmitResult.FAIL_ZERO_SUBSCRIBER : EmitResult.FAIL_OVERFLOW;
    }
    drain();
    return EmitResult.OK;
}
```

My question here: Why the local `q`? To my understanding, everything here could be implemented, just using `queue`. For me it looks like, the local variable is just adding code and thus complexity without any benefit.

Note: The method `Operator.setOnce(...)` tries to set a subscription, and returns false in case there is already one, or if the pipeline is cancelled already.

Comment: Probablu to get a "snapshot" of current value of non thread safe values

Comment: Is `queue` defined as `volatile`?

Comment: Yup.  This is about concurrency.  Because otherwise, the value of `queue` could change out from under you...

Comment: @BurakSerdar queue indeed is volatile.

Comment: Hmm, I think, I got it. This is necessary for the `for` loop that is busy waiting for the volatile `queue` to become non-null, and thus always needs to re-read the state. Thanks, for the comments.

Comment: @LouisWasserman The value of queue is maximally set once, which is controlled by the `if` statement. The `queue` itself is concurrent and thus state changes are thread-safe. I thus this, one could directly do `queue = Queues.<T>get(prefetch).get()` and `queue.offer()`.

Comment: @PeMa, volatile read/writes are more expensive than normal read/writes. This pattern is usually used to increase performance a bit by getting a snapshot of the volatile variable, and operating on the non-volatile snapshot. That said, the busy-loop is simply avoidable and bad programming in my opinion, and unless there is something we don't see, the first part of that if statement has a race condition and allows setting of the `queue` by multiple threads.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Yeah, performance is probably the reason. Even though it is only relevant for the first access, where the queue actually is null. However, I don't get why there is a race condition. The `Operator.setOnce()` is thread-safe and can only be `true` once in the lifecycle of the instance. The whole code is visible here https://github.com/reactor/reactor-core/blob/master/reactor-core/src/main/java/reactor/core/publisher/EmitterProcessor.java .

Comment: When `if q == null` runs, there is a chance that `queue` is already set by another thread and it is non-null.

Comment: @BurakSerdar Thanks for your comments. I think, I entirely got your point. Even thought, this isn't my code, it was quite helpful for understanding.

Comment: Related, possibly duplicate: [In ArrayBlockingQueue, why copy final member field into local final variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2785964/in-arrayblockingqueue-why-copy-final-member-field-into-local-final-variable)